# Mutating a new column on a datafame inside a List / dplyr / mutate / list / Rstudio

Tags: r, list, dplyr

sorry if this question is already solved, I have search without success to solve this doubt.

I scraped 10 seasons of the NBA and store the datasets inside a list but the main problem is that I don't have a column with the year of the season inside the datasets making difficult to identify from which season is the dataset coming.

So what im looking forward to do is to mutate a new column based on a vector of seasons and recognize the year of the season.

This is what I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

season_scrape <- c(2010:2019)
url <- paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_", season_scrape, "_totals.html")

scrape_function <- function(url){
  season_stats <- url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
    .[[1]] %>% 
    html_table() %>%
    mutate(season_year = season_scrape)
}

season_data <- lapply(url, scrape_function)
```

What would you recommend? mutate inside the scrape_function or after getting the dataset inside the list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in multiple ways. One way is to pass an additional `year` parameter in the function and apply the function using `Map` instead of `lapply`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

scrape_function <- function(url, year){
   url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
    .[[1]] %>% 
    html_table() %>%
    mutate(season_year = year)

}

season_data <- Map(scrape_function, url, season_scrape)
```

If you need to bind the data together into one dataframe, you can also use `map2_df` from `purrr`.

```
season_data <- purrr::map2_df(url, season_scrape, scrape_function)
```